# Modify Profile Biographical Info Field

Tags: users, profiles

I've been hunting for the hook to edit the Biographical info field and it's H3 but no luck. I've found edit_user_{$field} do specific hooks exist?

I'm thinking I can hook into the existing tag 'description'?
Thanks in advance.

```
edit_user_profile('description', 'change_description');
function change_description(){
// something here?
}
```

Comment: have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38819/how-to-remove-biography-from-user-profile-admin-page)?

Comment: If you've included a solution in your edit, it's better to instead answer your own question, then later mark is as accepted answer. It's more clear that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @toscho

A quick tweak on toscho's [Remove Bio Box](https://gist.github.com/toscho/1610331) code

```
add_action( 'personal_options', array ( 'T5_Hide_Profile_Bio_Box', 'start' ) );
/**
 * Captures the part with the biobox in an output buffer and removes it.
 *
 * @author Thomas Scholz, <info@toscho.de>
 *
 */
class T5_Hide_Profile_Bio_Box
{
    /**
     * Called on 'personal_options'.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function start()
    {
        $action = ( IS_PROFILE_PAGE ? 'show' : 'edit' ) . '_user_profile';
        add_action( $action, array ( __CLASS__, 'stop' ) );
        ob_start();
    }
/**
 * Strips the bio box from the buffered content.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public static function stop()
{
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // remove the headline
    $headline = __( IS_PROFILE_PAGE ? 'About Yourself' : 'About the user' );
    $replacement = 'About The Author Box';
    $html = str_replace( '<h3>' . $headline . '</h3>', '<h3>' . $replacement . '</h3>', $html );

    // remove the table row
    // $html = preg_replace( '~<tr>\s*<th><label for="description".*</tr>~imsUu', '<th><label for="description"</tr>', $html );
    $html = str_replace( 'Biographical Info', 'Short Author Bio', $html );
    print $html;
  }
}
```