# How to hide unused profile fields?

Tags: functions, javascript, profiles

There are fields that are in the the user profile that I do not need such as "Website" and "Biographical Info"...

I found a JS function to use to hide the fields from this answer ([link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94395/102168)), but I'm not sure where to implement it without changing the core files.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('input#url').closest('tr').remove();
    $('input#description').closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the JS part down, in order to have this script run, you can use the [`add_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) function and hook it to the [`admin_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head). This will run your custom JS script in the header of the `wp-admin` area.  Below is the code that you can add to your [child theme's](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) `function.php` file.

I've added a rule to only implement this JS function to the related profile pages such as `profile.php`, `user-edit.php`, and `user-new.php` so you won't see it there. Also, I prefer to use `hide()` instead of `remove()` because if you were to remove a required field (ex: Nickname) instead of hiding it, you will have trouble saving your profile. [See this link for the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12210735/6579923).

```
function wpse_238281_hide_profile_fields() { // Hide unused fields from user profile
    global $pagenow;
    $page = array(
        'profile.php',
        'user-edit.php',
        'user-new.php'
        );
    if ( in_array( $pagenow, $page, true ) ) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('input#url').closest('tr').hide();
                $('input#description').closest('tr').hide();
            } );
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```