# Use an array of page template slugs and $hook

Tags: hooks, wp-enqueue-script

I'm using the function below to load some javascript that removes the checkbox in the User Profile that is used to toggle the Visual Editor:

```
//Remove Visual Editor option in User Profile
function remove_visual_editor_admin_script( $hook ){
 if ('user-edit.php' != $hook) {
        return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'remove_visual_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/remove-visual-editor.js', array('jquery') );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','remove_visual_editor_admin_script');
```

It loads a simple jQuery function in `remove-visual-editor.js` that removes the HTML and CSS and hides the checkbox.

Problem is, the Visual Editor checkbox appears on two admin pages: one is `user-edit.php` and the other is `profile.php`; I'm calling the jQuery script on `user-edit.php` above.

So I tried an array of page templates, like this

```
if (array('user-edit.php', 'profile.php') != $hook) {
```

with no luck.

*How to I add the `remove-visual-editor.js` to both 'user-edit.php`and`profile.php` pages?*

Is there another way to add an array or multiple pages to the `if` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if ( in_array( $hook, [ 'user-edit.php', 'profile.php' ] ) )
    // do something
```

Or wait for the action `personal_options`, and enqueue the script for the footer. This action is fired in both cases. See [this old example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38900/73).

Comment: Thanks! Works great. I didn't know that there was no dedicated hook for user management.

Comment: Just found out this breaks in the 4.0 Beta. Had to go back to my original function above with no array.