# How do I hide specific user profile fields?

Tags: php, users

I am using a membership plugin which pulls default WordPress user profiles to a directory. I want to hide these fields from my registered site users. I have searched for plugins and found nothing that lets me "pick and choose". I also read [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38819/how-to-remove-biography-from-user-profile-admin-page?rq=1) but it doesn't address my needs.

In a perfect world (and in my wishful thinking) I would like to be able to know if there are a "list" of user profile fields and some code I could use to hide them. An example of this idea of a "list" of fields is in [this forum post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-fields-from-user-profile) on wordpress.org.

[image: These are the specific fields I would like to hide.]

Comment: Which membership plugin are you using? Also, is CSS "hiding" alone enough?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about CSS, yes that would be enough! I am using Paid Memberships Pro. However, I am not too concerned about what is showing up on the front end of the site. Members go to their user profile on the back-end of the site. The field in the screenshot I attached are what I'm interesting in hiding.